# This website does not know Turkish Language :(

Tags: ros, translation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's be honest! translate.google.com 's Turkish is not good.
I would like to translate the ROS Website and Documentation. But how will reach you with translations?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11156/this-website-does-not-know-turkish-language-:(/) by [Burak](https://answers.ros.org/users/1059/burak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-09-08

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Burak](https://answers.ros.org/users/1059/burak/) on 2011-09-09**:
I think, I can translate this web site. But, how I will give the turkish translation website for integration with English Version of ROS website?

**Comment by [SAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/880/sak/) on 2011-09-08**:
Your question is not clear. Do you mean, how you will give the turkish translated website for integration with English Version of ROS website??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A Turkish translation would be a great contribution.  So far, there are partial [Korean](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ko) and [Japanese](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ja) translations.  Seems like a Turkish translation should live at http://www.ros.org/wiki/tr.

---

Originally posted by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) with karma: 2916 on 2011-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2011-09-09**:
You need to create an account for the wiki first and log in.

**Comment by [Burak](https://answers.ros.org/users/1059/burak/) on 2011-09-09**:
"This page does not exist yet. What type of page are you trying to create?"
"Create new empty page"

"You do not have sufficient permission to make changes on this page."